# Tube Amp to Headphones

Tags: amplifiers, homerecording, vacuum-tube

I have a [B-52 AT-100](http://www.b-52stealthseries.com/AT100.html) all-tube amplifier head. I currently have it connected to a [LINE-6 Spider 412](https://www.zzounds.com/item--LINSPV412) four-speaker cabinet. In order to really drive the tubes, I have a vintage [Scholz Power Soak](https://www.rockman.fr/Reviews/Power_Soak.htm), which is a bunch of resistors that allow the user to step down the volume output while still running the head at maximum volume.

The setup looks kind of like this:

[image]

The quietest setting on the Power Soak is -32Db, which allows for playing at a reasonable volume while still driving the tubes at max power.

While the -32Db setting on the Power Soak is labeled "PHONES," presumably indicating that it's possible to drive headphones instead of a cabinet.

However, it's still really a lot of power output, I still have to turn down the main volume to about 30% in order to play it in my house. Without the Power Soak, it's likely that I'd blow out the windows in a fifteen mile radius.

In interests of space, I'd like to get rid of the cabinet and simply take the output of the Power Soak and route to actual headphones or a recording hub. I'm not really ever playing stadiums, so the cab is a bit overkill. However, I *really* like the sound of the amp being driven through the Power Soak.

What are my options for getting rid of my cabinet in a way that would allow me to play with headphones? I could always buy *another* Power Soak and step things down even further, but as I'm trying to reduce physical space as much as possible, is there a better option?

Comment: Do you really need to use such a massive full-tube head just for headphones practising? I know the Spider is much-hated for its sound, but for practising it should be pretty well-suited. In fact it'll almost certainly sound _better_ with headphones than the tube head does (because that doesn't have any cabinet emulation). And for recording or live, where sound really matters but loudness isn't such a problem, use the tube amp into a better cabinet, with or without the power soak.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of the power soak is not to reduce the signal level, but to offer a reliable low [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) like a cabinet, even if none is connected. A tube power amp requires such an impedance, else it'll destroy itself.

With the power soak in place and set to -32 dB, it doesn't really matter anymore what you connect. You can as well step it down yet a bit further with a simple voltage divider. This can be built from ordinary resistors<sup>†</sup>, which you can buy for less than 1$.

[image: Schematic of how to further step down signal level after power soak.]

You can also use a passive headphones splitter with volume control, that's the same as a voltage divider but with a dial.

Just, as I already commented, this doesn't really make any sense. Even the best tube amp does *not* sound “right” if it's not connected to a proper guitar cabinet (either real or simulated). Many power-soak-like devices have simple cabinet emulation built in for recording or headphones use. In that case, the headphones output also has an extra volume control.

If you want *good sound*, you'll need the cabinet. The usually more sensible alternative is to just go all-digital for practising.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Basically, the power soak also consists only of simple resistors, but these need to be able to dissipate lots of power, which is the real engineering challenge.</sub>